# How to compile and run Servlet using tomcat on netbeans while having tomcat and code in different directories?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

When I compile the code in netbeans it shows no errors. However, when I run the code using netbeans after starting tomcat is does not deploy on web browser it only shows Waiting for Tomcat in details section?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Tomcat first in your Netbeans.

eg.

```
Netbeans 7.x & above -> Tools -> Servers-> Add server -> select your Tomcat from your local directory.
```

And follow these complete [tutorial](https://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/02/installing-tomcat-7-and-configuring-as-server-in-netbeans/). Hope it help.

Comment: Thank you, for your response. I have already followed the steps which are shown in the mentioned tutorial and got the confirmation page of Apache Tomcat congratulating me on successfully installing tomcat. I have also done changes in 'environmental variables'. but the mentioned is same. I have also tried this using eclipse but this problem exist with eclipse as well.

Comment: if you finished, just right click your project and run with tomcat server.

Comment: Not working. My tomcat is in C:/ drive and my netbeans is creating my project in D:/ drive does this make any difference and if yes, then please tell me what do I do?